# Deployment flutter into github pages give "Repository name with UpperCase" is not a valid Dart package name

Tags: flutter, github, yaml, workflow, github-actions

I have created a workflow in github action to build a flutter web app and deploy it into github page.
The name of the flutter repository that i am working into it come with uppercase.

```
...
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          channel: stable
      - uses: username/RepoWithUpperCase@main
...
```

In this case when the workflow come to this action step:

```
- run: flutter create .
  shell: bash
  working-directory: ${{inputs.workingDir}}
```

give this error

> "RepoWithUpperCase" is not a valid Dart package name.

I solved this error by rename the repository to lowerCase by refer to [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53106#issuecomment-821095023)

So my question is: how to solve this issue without rename the repository, in other word how the repository to be cloned in the Ubuntu VM with directory name use small caps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the directory is the default when creating a new flutter app using `flutter create .`.

You can change the name by passing `--project-name`, like so:

```
> flutter create --project-name repo_with_upper_case .
```

NB: are you sure you need to run `flutter create` every time though? Isn't the repo you're cloning already a flutter project?

Comment: as the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/web#add-web-support-to-an-existing-app) `flutter create .` enable web support to an existing flutter project

Comment: I don't think you need to run this every time. You could probably run it once on your machine and commit the relevant files / changes.